# Vuetify.js data-table fixed-header scrolling via CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

The [Vuetify's `v-data-table` component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables) has a `fixed-header` feature, which makes the header sticky when the `height` is less than the table height.

It is working when the `height` is set explicitly.

HTML:

```
    <v-content id="mycontent">
      <v-container fluid id="mycontainer">
        <h2>Header</h2>
        <div id="outer">
          <v-data-table id="mytable" :headers="headers" :items="items" :height="height"
                        fixed-header disable-pagination disable-sort hide-default-footer>
          </v-data-table>
        </div>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
```

CSS:

```
#mycontent {
}
#mycontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#outer {
  flex: 1;
}
#mytable {
}
#mytable table {
  width: auto;
}
```

JS:

```
  data: () => ({
    headers: [
      { text: "Header A", value: "a" },
      { text: "Header B, longer", value: "b" },
      { text: "Header C", value: "c" }
    ],
    height: 100
  }),
  computed: {
    items() {
      var items = [];
      for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
        items.push({ a: "Row " + i, b: "Column B", c: "Column C" });
      }
      return items;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onResize() {
      this.height = document.getElementById("outer").clientHeight;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onResize);
    this.$nextTick(this.onResize);
  }
```

[Live demo](https://codepen.io/rustyx/pen/abowyPx)

But is it possible to achieve the same effect with pure CSS, or at least without setting `height` explicitly?

Answer (score 5):

Try using `height clac`

```
.v-data-table__wrapper{height:calc(100vh - 150px) !important;}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to hardcode the `150px` part.

Comment: Those 150px is the your header and footer size. so based on screen size your table will different.

Comment: In my case the header size is dynamic, so no couldn't use this.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a little article explaining my solution to this problem using `position: sticky`: https://medium.com/@jareklipski/sticky-table-header-in-vuetify-js-fab39988dc3

The overall idea is to set the `<th>` position to sticky and `top` value to `0` (or height of your fixed site header). Only one obstacle is that Vuetify.js data table has overflow, which can be addressed by `/deep/` selector:

```
.v-data-table /deep/ .v-data-table__wrapper {
  overflow: unset;
}
```

Here's a complete working example: https://github.com/loomchild/sticky-vuetify-table-header

Comment: Oh, that's right! Special highlight is that you have to `unset` both `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` (for what `overflow` is shortcut), not just `overflow-y`.

Comment: The /deep/ directive is depreciated and not respected anymore on modern browsers. Hence, the solution fails.

Comment: As far as I know, in this particular case /deep/ selector is compiled by Vue and not exposed to the browser (https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors). Could you confirm that the solution doesn't work for you (the demo can be found here: https://3o0km.sse.codesandbox.io/, it works correctly for me on latest FF and Chrome).

Comment: The working example doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your table to always take fixed size in a page you should set max-height and remove height attribute from v-data-table.

```
#mytable .v-data-table__wrapper {
  max-height: 300px;
}
```